# Laravel 5.2 validation: date_format:Y.m.d not working

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I try to validate a POST request.

The format is: `d.m.Y` (12.1.2017)
My rule is `required|date_format:d.m.Y` for this field.

I get this error message:

```
InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 425:
Unexpected data found.
Unexpected data found.
Data missing
```

If I change the `.` to `-` or even `/` it is working -> POST data changed before to match the rule.

I need the German format for this.

edit:
My validation rules:

```
public function rules()
{
    return  [
        'title' => 'required|max:255',
        'expiration_date' => 'required|date_format:d.m.Y',
        //'description' => 'required',
        'provision_agent' => 'required|integer|between:0,100',
        'discount_consumer' => 'required|integer|between:0,100',
        'quota' => 'required|integer',
    ];
}
```

Comment: I guess it is somehow related to the fact that `.` is a special char in the validation rule strings, normally used by Llaravel for other reasons - but no idea how that can be escaped

Comment: Have you tried \. ? Or `['field'=> 'date_format' => ['required','d.m.Y']]`? Also, could you show us more of your code?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte is that syntax documented anywhere? Just curious ...

Comment: I don't know. It has been a couple months since I worked in a project using Laravel, can't remember much :(

Comment: @FelippeDuarte That is not even a valid array :-( two times `=>`

Comment: validation rules added to my question

Comment: @mht Wrap date_format:"d.m.Y"should work i just tired with 5.2 it's working fine. I think the error something else in your code Not with validation rule

Comment: @mht Show us the code where your using that expiration_date in your controller or model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap your Format should work i just tried with 5.2 it's working fine.

```
public function rules()
{
    return  [
        'title' => 'required|max:255',
        'expiration_date' => 'required|date_format:"d.m.Y"',
        //'description' => 'required',
        'provision_agent' => 'required|integer|between:0,100',
        'discount_consumer' => 'required|integer|between:0,100',
        'quota' => 'required|integer',
    ];
}
```

But the error what you added in question  **InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 425:** it seems something else my guess you are using **expiration_date** some where in controller or model like this with **Carbon**

```
 echo Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '12.1.2017');
```

You should try something like this

```
echo Carbon::parse('12.1.2017')->format('Y-m-d')
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your format into quotes:

```
'date_format:"d.m.Y"'
```

Comment: Tried it but same problem. I think . is a used operator in the validation. I need to escape it but cant find if its possible or not.

Comment: @mht Wrap should work i just tired with 5.2 it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
public function rules()
{
    return  [
        'title' => 'required|max:255',
        'expiration_date' => 'date_format:"d.m.Y"|required', // I have changed order of validation
        //'description' => 'required',
        'provision_agent' => 'required|integer|between:0,100',
        'discount_consumer' => 'required|integer|between:0,100',
        'quota' => 'required|integer',
    ];
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I don't think change of order will work but Wrap will work. And after date_format validation . There is no use of required here?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't succeed solving the issue otherwise, you can still use a [custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-validation-rules):

```
Validator::extend('date_dmY', function ($attribute, $value) {
    $format = 'd.m.Y';
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $value);
    return $date && $date->format($format) === $value;
}, 'optional error message');
```

The extra check `$date->format($format) === $value` is to avoid erroneously accepting out-of-range dates, e.g. "32.01.2017". See this [comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205) on php.net.

Once the custom validation rule has been defined, you can use it like so:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        'expiration_date' => 'required|date_dmY',
    ];
}
```